# Cannot compile, missing libncurses5-dev

Tags: debian, kernel, apt, compiling, libraries

When I try

```
make menuconfig
```

I get this

```
Install ncurses (ncurses-devel or libncurses-dev
```

When I try to install it

```
Package libncurses5-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.

aptitude search libncurses
    i   libncurses5                     - shared libraries for terminal handling    
i A libncurses5:i386                - shared libraries for terminal handling    
i   libncursesw5                    - shared libraries for terminal handling (wi
```

Where I can find libncurses5-dev ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try what was suggested? i.e. `libncurses-dev` or `ncurses-devel` ? Not `libncurses5-dev`

Which distro/version are you using?

Looks like `libncurses-dev` is a virtual package which brings up `libncurses5-dev` in Ubuntu 16.04. Fedora 28 has `ncurses-devel` available in the updates repo.

Comment: Using debian    `Package libncurses-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source`             and ncurses    `E: Unable to locate package ncurses-devel
`

Comment: Which version? Check that the relevant repositories are enabled. `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: `deb http://ftp.ua.debian.org/debian/ stretch-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.ua.debian.org/debian/ stretch-backports main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.ua.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.ua.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main`

Comment: Do not bury this information in answer comments.  Put it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

To install [`libncurses5-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libncurses5-dev) ,you should have the following line in your `sources.list` ([from the comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452140/cannot-compile-missing-libncurses5-dev/452222#comment821173_452141) ):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
```

Run :

```
# echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# apt update
# apt install libncurses5-dev
```

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by using the archive source repository: `echo deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main >> /etc/apt/sources.list`